# Differential Notation Misunderstanding

Tags: calculus

Consider I have a function $v=e^u$ where u is from the set of all Real numbers. Now, if I take the derivative here, I can get $dv/du = e^u$. If I multiply both sides by the $du$, I will get $dv=e^u*du$. However, if I interpret this $dv$ and $du$ as $\Delta v$ and as $\Delta u$, I can write this statement: $\Delta v = e^{\Delta u}$. If we take the limit as $u$ approaches $0$, then we will get $dv=e^{du}$ However, this is not the same as $dv=e^u*du$. What went wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: What you get is $\Delta v = e^u \Delta u$, not $\Delta v = e^{\Delta u}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Delta v=e^{u+\Delta u}-e^u=e^u(e^{\Delta u}-1),$$ not $$e^{\Delta u}.$$

By the way,

$$\lim_{\Delta u\to0}\frac{e^{\Delta u}-1}{\Delta u}=1,$$ and this justifies

$$\frac{dv}{du}=e^u=v.$$

Comment: I see, I forgot that we were looking at the point u. Thanks.